# How do you serialize a Map to JSON in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, dictionary, lift

So I have a Map in Scala like this:

```
val m = Map[String, String](
    "a" -> "theA",
    "b" -> "theB",
    "c" -> "theC",
    "d" -> "theD",
    "e" -> "theE"
)
```

and I want to serialize this structure into a JSON string using lift-json.

Do any of you know how to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about this?

```
implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
import net.liftweb.json.Extraction._
import net.liftweb.json.Printer._
val m = Map[String, String](
    "a" -> "theA",
    "b" -> "theB",
    "c" -> "theC",
    "d" -> "theD",
    "e" -> "theE"
)
println(compact(render(decompose(m))))
```

output:

```
{"e":"theE","a":"theA","b":"theB","c":"theC","d":"theD"}
```

EDIT:

For a `scala.collections.mutable.Map`, you should convert it first to an immutable map: `.toMap`

Comment: When I change the type to scala.collections.mutable.Map, the output becomes: [{"_1":"d","_2":"theD"},{"_1":"a","_2":"theA"},{"_1":"c","_2":"theC"},{"_1":"b","_2":"theB"},{"_1":"e","_2":"theE"}], which makes me kind of sad.

Comment: There is an easy workaround for this -- just call .toMap on the mutable map to get an immutable map, and then things work okay again.

Answer (score 37):

If you are using the latest Scala 2.10.x and above :

```
println(scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject(m))
```

Comment: It's been removed from Scala 2.11 and above.

Comment: @Soid looks like it's still there : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/scala-parser-combinators/#scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject

Comment: I might make a mistake somewhere. But were you able to use it? What version of scala-parser-combinators did you use (a full maven dependency would be helpful)?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't recurse correctly into the object. For example, `Map("0" -> 1, "1" -> List(Map("2" -> 3)))` is stringified to `{"0" : 1, "1" : List(Map(2 -> 3))}`.

Comment: Beware, it does not recurse, and will translate nested objects to their string representation!

Answer (score 9):

You can roll your own pretty easily (yay, no dependencies). This one does basic handling of types and will do recursion unlike `JSONObject` that was mentioned:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object JsonConverter {
  def toJson(o: Any) : String = {
    var json = new ListBuffer[String]()
    o match {
      case m: Map[_,_] => {
        for ( (k,v) <- m ) {
          var key = escape(k.asInstanceOf[String])
          v match {
            case a: Map[_,_] => json += "\"" + key + "\":" + toJson(a)
            case a: List[_] => json += "\"" + key + "\":" + toJson(a)
            case a: Int => json += "\"" + key + "\":" + a
            case a: Boolean => json += "\"" + key + "\":" + a
            case a: String => json += "\"" + key + "\":\"" + escape(a) + "\""
            case _ => ;
          }
        }
      }
      case m: List[_] => {
        var list = new ListBuffer[String]()
        for ( el <- m ) {
          el match {
            case a: Map[_,_] => list += toJson(a)
            case a: List[_] => list += toJson(a)
            case a: Int => list += a.toString()
            case a: Boolean => list += a.toString()
            case a: String => list += "\"" + escape(a) + "\""
            case _ => ;
          }
        }
        return "[" + list.mkString(",") + "]"
      }
      case _ => ;
    }
    return "{" + json.mkString(",") + "}"
  }

  private def escape(s: String) : String = {
    return s.replaceAll("\"" , "\\\\\"");
  }
}
```

You can see it in action like

```
println(JsonConverter.toJson(
    Map("a"-> 1,
        "b" -> Map(
            "nes\"ted" -> "yeah{\"some\":true"),
            "c" -> List(
                1,
                2,
                "3",
                List(
                    true,
                    false,
                    true,
                    Map(
                        "1"->"two",
                        "3"->"four"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

{"a":1,"b":{"nes\"ted":"yeah{\"some\":true"},"c":[1,2,"3",[true,false,true,{"1":"two","3":"four"}]]}
```

(It's part of a Coinbase GDAX library I've written, see [util.scala](https://github.com/jar-o/gdax-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/GDAX/util.scala))

Answer (score 6):

You can use this simple way if you are using play framework:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

Json.toJson(<your_map>)
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will convert many different objects, and doesn't require any libraries beyond the built-in the `scala.util.parsing.json._`. It won't properly handle edge cases like Maps with integers as keys.

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.{JSONArray, JSONObject}
def toJson(arr: List[Any]): JSONArray = {
  JSONArray(arr.map {
    case (innerMap: Map[String, Any]) => toJson(innerMap)
    case (innerArray: List[Any])      => toJson(innerArray)
    case (other)                      => other
  })
}
def toJson(map: Map[String, Any]): JSONObject = {
  JSONObject(map.map {
    case (key, innerMap: Map[String, Any]) =>
      (key, toJson(innerMap))
    case (key, innerArray: List[Any]) =>
      (key, toJson(innerArray))
    case (key, other) =>
      (key, other)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Einar's solution, you can use JSONObject from [Parser Combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) to do this.  Note that it does not recurse, you'll need to do this yourself.  The library also includes JSONArray, for list like data structures.  Something like the following will address Noel's concerns about nested structures.  This example does not recurse to an arbitrary level, but will handle a value of **List[Map[String, Any]]**.

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.{JSONArray, JSONObject}

def toJson(m : Map[String, Any]): String = JSONObject(
  m.mapValues {
    case mp: Map[String, Any] => JSONObject(mp)
    case lm: List[Map[String, Any]] => JSONArray(lm.map(JSONObject(_)))
    case x => x
    }
  ).toString
```

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing the answer by @Raja.

For those nested object, I locally modify the class to have my wanted `toString()` like this way:

`case class MList[T]() extends MutableList[T] {
  override def toString() = "[" + this.toList.mkString(",") + "]"
}`

Then inside the Map object, I use this `MList` instead of the standard `List`. That way, my `map` object prints out fine by calling `JSONObject(map).toString()`.