# How to Convert Scala Map to JValue using LIft?

Tags: json, scala, dictionary, lift-json

i am new to Lift-Json and Scala
i am working on collections, i want to convert map to JSON to String to write on file.

i tried to use

```
val json1 = compact(JsonAST.render(map))
```

but not taking map.. asking need JValue.

how to convert Map to JValue and am i working on right way or not.

i want to save data on file. i created a Map and converting to JSON to String and writing on file

first i used JacksMapper it worked fine but performace is low. thats why i am trying Lift-Json

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271386/how-do-you-serialize-a-map-to-json-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/#net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL
there is a an implicit function that makes map to Jvalue
and then use pretty(render(json))

the function pretty is in json.Printer